# Fetching Width of Range Slider Input

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider, range

I'm looking to fetch the width of the class iris-bar in the js function addMarks. Getting this value will then allow me to change the colour of Markers placed along the line of my range slider according to the width of the line.

- I'm looking to change the color of  using "if less than or equal to" statement.
- I have multiple range sliders on one page so need to fetch the value of the line for the individual range sliders and apply to the slider.
- The class name of the line is "iris-line".
- Defining `var line = $(".iris-bar").width();` outputs 'undefined' using console.log.

Range sliders will ultimately look like this:
[image]

**HTML**

```
<div class="range-slider">
    <span class="irs irs--round js-irs-0">
      <span class="irs">

        <span class="irs-line" tabindex="0"></span>

        <span class="irs-min" style="visibility: visible;">0</span>
        <span class="irs-max" style="visibility: visible;">4</span>
        <span class="irs-from" style="visibility: hidden;">0</span>
        <span class="irs-to" style="visibility: hidden;">0</span>
        <span class="irs-single" style="left: 48.7239%;">2</span>

      </span>

      <span class="irs-grid"></span>
      <span class="irs-bar irs-bar--single" style="left: 0px; width: 50%;"></span>
      <span class="irs-shadow shadow-single" style="display: none;"></span>

      <span class="mark" style="background-color: #005190; left: 0%;"></span>
      <span class="mark" style="background-color: #005190; left: 25%;"></span>
      <span class="mark" style="background-color: #005190; left: 50%;"></span>
      <span class="mark" style="background-color: #CCDCE9; left: 75%;"></span>
      <span class="mark" style="background-color: #CCDCE9; left: 100%;"></span>

     </span>

    <input type="text" class="js-range-slider irs-hidden-input" value="" tabindex="-1" readonly="">
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
var $range = $(".js-range-slider");
var min = 0;
var max = 4;
var marks = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4];


$range.ionRangeSlider({
    skin: "round",
    grid: false,
    min: min,
    max: max,
    step: 1,
    from: 2,
    onStart: function (data) {
        addMarks(data.slider);
    }
});

function convertToPercent (num) {
    var percent = (num - min) / (max - min) * 100;    
    return percent;
}

function addMarks ($slider) {
    var html = '';
    var left = 0;

    // need to define the width of iris-bar here
    var line = ;

    var i;    
    for (i = 0; i < marks.length; i++) {
        left = convertToPercent(marks[i]);

        if (left <= line) {
            color = '#005190';
        } else {
            color = '#CCDCE9';
        }
        html += '<span class="mark" style="background-color: '+ color +'; left: ' + left + '%; -webkit-transform: translate(-' + left + '%, 0); -moz-transform: translate(-' + left + '%, 0); -ms-transform: translate(-' + left + '%, 0); -o-transform: translate(-' + left + '%, 0); -transform: translate(-' + left + '%, 0);"></span>';
    }

    $slider.append(html);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need the width of an element, and since you are using jQuery you can simple use $("element").width().

```
var MyWidth = $(".iris-bar").width();
```

Comment: Adding that in returns "undefined" when I spit it out to the consol.log

Comment: You sure its not a typo? Here its working fine, i can get the correct value for .iris-bar :/ try to give it an id and go for the id.

Comment: No not a typo. Needs to be a class as the range slider gets repeated.